# How to get value from texbox in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery autocomplete method, I got country value from local json file. but couldn't get value in autocomplete textbox, i followed more example couldn't solve. can you please some suggestions..

Code Here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>DevBridge Autocomplete Demo</title>
    <link href="content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Ajax Lookup</h2>
        <p>Type country name in english</p>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 80px;">
            <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; background: transparent;"/>
            <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete" disabled="disabled" style="color: #CCC; position: absolute; background: transparent; z-index: 1;"/>
        </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/countries.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sample(){         
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/json-autocomplete/auto.json',
                success: function(callback) {
                    for(i=0;i<=callback.RestResponse.result.length;i++){
                       var test=(callback.RestResponse.result[i].country);
                       console.log(test);
                    }
                },
            });
        }
        sample();



$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: sample(),
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log(suggestion);
    }
});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your sample function is not returning anything. could you please provide any code snippet.

Comment: According to official jquery autocomplete documentation, there is no `lookup` method. However, there is a `source` method that might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using this https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

coding, I can get ajax callback function answer ["IND","AUS"]. But i couldn't pass lookup method. Could you please resolve my issue.

Comment: Hi Singh, could you please resolve my issues.

Comment: Do you get selected country value in  console.log(suggestion); ?

Comment: @user5561847 Please add codepen for your issue